# How to send a voicemail for outbound calls in case of no-answer using Twilio Voice?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, outbound, voicemail

I cannot find a way to send a no-answer outbound call to go straight to mailbox.

I tried to use AMD to handle the flow of call but it did not work for me. If a call is declined, I get a voicemail on an answering machine. If I let the phone ring and let the call go unanswered, I do not get a voicemail on my device.

```cs
Twilio.TwilioClient.Init(username, password);
CallResource call = CallResource.Create(+1xxxxxxxxx, +1xxxxxxxxx,
   twiml: <Response> <Say> Enjoy! </Say>  </Response>",  //detail of voice
   timeout: 60, 
   statusCallback: new Uri(https://test.com/api/Callback),
   statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
   statusCallbackEvent: ["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
   machineDetection: "DetectMessageEnd"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the `twiml` parameter, the TwiML instructions will be executed immediately, while the AMD process is still trying to detect whether a human is answering or an answering machine. You should specify the `url` parameter pointing to a webhook handler that reads the `AnsweredBy` parameter and if it is `machine_end_beep`, respond with the TwiML you'd like.

Here's an example. The code below creates the call using the `url` parameter which Twilio will call once AMD determines who is answering the call.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
    .Build();

TwilioClient.Init(config["TwilioAccountSid"], config["TwilioAuthToken"]);

CallResource.Create(
    new PhoneNumber("+1xxxxxxxxxxx"),
    new PhoneNumber("+1xxxxxxxxxxx"),
    timeout: 60,
    url: new Uri("https://hostname/handler"),
    machineDetection: "DetectMessageEnd"
);
```

The webhook handler looks like this:

```cs
using Twilio.AspNet.Core;
using Twilio.TwiML;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/handler", async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var form = await request.ReadFormAsync();

    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    if (form["AnsweredBy"] == "machine_end_beep")
    {
        response.Say("Your order has been delivered to the store, please pick it up at your earliest convenience.");
    }
    if (form["AnsweredBy"] == "human")
    {
        response.Say("Hi human");
    }

    return Results.Extensions.TwiML(response);
});

app.Run();
```

`AnsweredBy` can also be other values than the two cases above, as shown in the [AMD docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#webhook-parameters).
The ASP.NET Core app is using [the Twilio helper library for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet) to handle the webhook.